# Give an example of a group $G$ and subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $HK=\{hk\mid h\in H,k\in K\}$ is not a subgroup of $G.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Pretty much the question in the title. I had an answer and wanted to know if I did it correctly-

I picked $G$ as the $U(5) - \{1\} = \{2,3,4\}$ under the operation multiplication modulo 5.

$H=\{2\}$ and $K=\{3\}$. Then $HK = \{1\}$ which is not $G$. Would this be correct? I looked up a few solutions online, and they all seemed to be more complicated than this. Am I missing something here?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be using MathJax by now. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Also, I'd be very surprised if this question hasn't been addressed here before.

Comment: I don't think that your $G$ is a group, or that $H$ or $K$ are groups.

Comment: In particular, a group needs to contain an identity element. If you remove the identity element from $U(5)$, it's no longer a group. Same thing with choosing a subset of a group which does not contain the identity element.

Comment: $G$ is not a group, because $2 \times 3$ is not in $G$.

Comment: @JonathanPal I see. Thank you.

Comment: one other hint is that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ where $HK = KH$ (as sets), then $HK$ must be a subgroup of $G$ (this is non-obvious but has been proved on math.SE before). so you would need to be using a non-commutative group in your counterexample; $U(5)$ is commutative